# How is the tag prefixing the window title chosen?

Tags: discussion

[image: screenshot]

I noticed that for some questions the first tag is chosen and for others that last one is chosen. Why is that?

Comment: I think it is the most "popular" tag

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I don't think so. In the above screenshot, `entity-framework` is much more popular than `lambda`, yet the latter was chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title), [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) is shown in the title because [entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) is already in the question's title.